# 2019 MacBook Pro, Kernel panic

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, error, kernel-panic

I've had my 13 inch 2019 MacBook Pro for almost a year now. Over the 3 weeks or so, it has begun randomly restarting or crashing every once and a while. I haven't changed my usage habits, or downloaded any new programs, however, I did recently start using my external hard drive again so I can have daily Time Machine backups. (I had bought it in January and used it at my office daily, but then didn't have access to it for 3 months due to COVID restrictions.) It seems unlikely to me that that could be the cause, as I bought the hard drive from Target and it doesn't seem suspicious.

Over the last 3 weeks or so, occasionally when I am working the screen will just go black, and the haptic feedback from 3D touch will stop, as if it ran out of battery, but it didn't. Then, when I start it back up, I will get a Problem Report for macOS popup that says my computer restarted because of a problem. At first I assumed this was possibly related to the fact that I hadn't updated my macOS in far too long, so I updated to Catalina, but the issue keeps happening.

I am including the error report here in the hopes someone smarter than me can help me figure out what's wrong and how to fix it. Thank you so much for your help in advance:

```
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff7f94bd9d17): @/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IOUSBHostFamily_Drivers/IOUSBHostFamily-800.141.1/AppleUSBXHCI/AppleUSBXHCITransferRing.cpp:139
Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff92245c37f0 : 0xffffff801151a65d 
0xffffff92245c3840 : 0xffffff8011654a75 
0xffffff92245c3880 : 0xffffff80116465fe 
0xffffff92245c38d0 : 0xffffff80114c0a40 
0xffffff92245c38f0 : 0xffffff8011519d27 
0xffffff92245c39f0 : 0xffffff801151a117 
0xffffff92245c3a40 : 0xffffff8011cc1abc 
0xffffff92245c3ab0 : 0xffffff7f94bd9d17 
0xffffff92245c3ac0 : 0xffffff7f94bbc734 
0xffffff92245c3b00 : 0xffffff7f94bd33c8 
0xffffff92245c3b20 : 0xffffff7f94bd9aa5 
0xffffff92245c3b40 : 0xffffff7f94bd93fc 
0xffffff92245c3b80 : 0xffffff7f94e61958 
0xffffff92245c3bb0 : 0xffffff8011c2ea28 
0xffffff92245c3c10 : 0xffffff7f91ffdaea 
0xffffff92245c3c60 : 0xffffff7f920319f9 
0xffffff92245c3c80 : 0xffffff8011c2ea28 
0xffffff92245c3ce0 : 0xffffff7f92012d52 
0xffffff92245c3d30 : 0xffffff8011c2ea28 
0xffffff92245c3d90 : 0xffffff7f9200f23d 
0xffffff92245c3db0 : 0xffffff8011bfe0b5 
0xffffff92245c3de0 : 0xffffff8011c059e3 
0xffffff92245c3e60 : 0xffffff7f9201d69d 
0xffffff92245c3ea0 : 0xffffff7f92009c04 
0xffffff92245c3ec0 : 0xffffff801155c605 
0xffffff92245c3f40 : 0xffffff801155c131 
0xffffff92245c3fa0 : 0xffffff80114c013e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.2)[46B74D4B-F96A-3C3D-9373-CA956389608C]@0xffffff7f91fe4000->0xffffff7f920ddfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController(1.0)[FF1BAE1C-CA7A-3DF2-810C-D5372B240604]@0xffffff7f91fca000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties(1.2)[77AA2487-AE0D-364A-BD0A-6361747DAB91]@0xffffff7f91fd2000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon(1.0)[FD7E16C9-CC6D-3595-8E03-291F9DA0397E]@0xffffff7f91fd6000
         com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI(1.2)[1F700485-12DC-38D7-A500-E110FE1EFE3C]@0xffffff7f94ba3000->0xffffff7f94bfafff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[68557A36-4EE1-372A-983B-BB2769FDB8E0]@0xffffff7f91f09000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.2)[46B74D4B-F96A-3C3D-9373-CA956389608C]@0xffffff7f91fe4000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon(1.0)[FD7E16C9-CC6D-3595-8E03-291F9DA0397E]@0xffffff7f91fd6000
         com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI(1.2)[F792C041-4B00-3AA8-ADBC-01D43D648A68]@0xffffff7f94e59000->0xffffff7f94e8dfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[68557A36-4EE1-372A-983B-BB2769FDB8E0]@0xffffff7f91f09000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[B130A8B7-967F-330E-942F-E0BB93C71C56]@0xffffff7f91f12000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.2)[46B74D4B-F96A-3C3D-9373-CA956389608C]@0xffffff7f91fe4000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon(1.0)[FD7E16C9-CC6D-3595-8E03-291F9DA0397E]@0xffffff7f91fd6000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI(1.2)[1F700485-12DC-38D7-A500-E110FE1EFE3C]@0xffffff7f94ba3000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19G73

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Sun Jul  5 00:43:10 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.1~9/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 783946EA-6F11-3647-BF90-787AEA14B954
Kernel slide:     0x0000000011200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8011400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8011300000
System model name: MacBookPro15,4 (Mac-53FDB3D8DB8CA971)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 6151369211758
last loaded kext at 6024279518694: >Core!SFsck  551 (addr 0xffffff7f956ef000, size 106496)
last unloaded kext at 2030655064956: >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice    1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f955d6000, size 45056)
loaded kexts:
>Core!SFsck 551
>AudioAUUC  1.70
|SCSITaskUserClient 422.120.3
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.6
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.6
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f7
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>pmtelemetry    1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.7
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.70.7
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.70.7
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.429
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.7
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>usb.realtek8153patcher 5.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
>!A!BModule 1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AXsanScheme   3
>usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
>usb.serial 6.0.0
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.6
|IOAVB!F    850.1
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.6
>!UAudio    323.4
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f7
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.6
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.3
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>Core!S 551
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    7.0.6f7
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f7
>!A!BDebug  1
>!AConvergedIPCOLYBTControl 1
>!A!BDebugService   1
>!AConvergedPCI 1
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!AMultiFunctionManager 1
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f7
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f7
>!ASSE  1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Kernel panics are usually caused by hardware problems. The report you posted suggests it is a problem with a USB device, but it could be anything, really.

I suggest running [Apple Hardware Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) (be sure to unplug all your USB devices etc. as it says in the instructions). If it fails, call Apple about getting your MacBook repaired. If it succeeds, run it a second time just to be sure.

If no hardware problems are found, then stop using your external drive and see if the panics stop. It might be the drive, or it might be the drive's power connector, or it might be the USB cable connecting the drive, or it might be some other USB device attached (like an external keyboard), or it could be something else entirely. It's pretty much trial and error if the hardware diagnostics do not turn up anything.